# Liferay 6.2 deployment fails with missing/unavailable dependencies on JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, liferay, liferay-6

In *JBoss* start-up log:

> 12:47:37,481 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed -
>   address: ([("deployment" => "liferay-portal.war")]) - failure
>   description: {*"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable
>   dependencies" => ["jboss.web.deployment.default-host./.realm is
>   missing [jboss.security.security-domain.PortalRealm]"]*}
>
> JBAS014775: *New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:*
>         service jboss.security.security-domain.PortalRealm (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./.realm]

Answer (score 2):

You have missed one configuration in your standalone.xml file.

Add the following JAAS security domain to the security subsystem  defined in element

```html
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">

  <security-domain name="PortalRealm">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="com.liferay.portal.security.jaas.PortalLoginModule" flag="required" />
    </authentication>
  </security-domain>
```

For more information, please refer below link.

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/installing-liferay-on-jboss-7-4

Comment: Thanks. But I had added that entry in standalone-full.xml file.

Comment: Subsystem here is <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">

Comment: thts fine with security:1.2. Can you let me know what is the jboss server version and specific liferay 6.2.x version (what is maintenance version)

Comment: jboss-eap-6.4.0-installer, liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4, liferay-portal-dependencies-6.2-ce-ga4 and DB: postgresql-9.4.3-1

Comment: Prabhu, is your problem solved? As I replicated whole setup locally and everything works fine for me as per link mentioned above.

Comment: I have the problem still.

Comment: Can you provide the link for installing JBoss 7.1.x on RHEL ?

Comment: www.jboss.org/download-manager/file/jboss-eap-6.4.0.GA.zip...as I am registered in jboss.

Comment: There were DB connectivity issues. I resolved and installation was successful. Thanks Neeraj.